# JmDNS on Android

Tags: android, zeroconf, jmdns, mdns

Have you succeeded in service discovery using jmdns in Android? I'm facing same problem not able to discover services using jmdns in Android.

From my code using jmdns I am trying to discover services of type:

```
jmdns.addServiceListener("_afpovertcp._tcp.", listener);
ServiceInfo[] infos = jmdns.list("_afpovertcp._tcp.");
```

I have installed _afpovertcp._tcp service type (Avahi package) on my Linux Ubuntu PC. My Android phone with my code and linux machine both are configured to WI-FI. Still not able to discover my Linux PC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes make sure you are using the latest jMDNS from Sourceforge in their SVN repo and you can see our example in Android here from our open source app.

http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-plus/source/browse/trunk/src/org/tunesremote/LibraryActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Add the internet permission to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In addition you have to implement the listener. Can you show us your implementation?
It has to look like here:
[Samples with JmDNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276487/samples-with-jmdns)